# Wordpress: Figure out what page number a post would have on the index screen

Tags: php, wordpress

I can't seem to figure the following out:
In a Wordpress theme I'm developing, 10 excerpts will be displayed at a time on the index screen. Naturally, then, if there are 20 posts the newest 10 posts will be displayed on page 1 and the 10 oldest on page 2 of the index screen.

When viewing any single post I would like to have a function which prints the page number upon which the current post would be found when viewing the index screen.

I've tried doing WP_queries, like:

```
$args = array(
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'after'     => get_the_date,

...
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

but with no luck.

Would anybody out there have any suggestions in which direction I should go about for figuring this one out!?! Any help is much obliged!

Answer (score 0):

you could do a query on your page and figure out where your post would be....

```
$id = get_the_ID(); // set within your loop

$args = array(
'date_query' => array(
    array(
        'after'     => get_the_date,

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

$i=1;
foreach($query as $post=>$key){
   if($key->ID == $id) {//not tested have a look at the object to get correct location
      $postnumber= $i;
   }
 $i++;
}

$page= $postnumber / 10;
$pagenumber= round($page, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
```

seems heavy on resources though!

Answer (score 0):

```
I would probably opt for counting posts newer than the current one.

    // This is not tested code, just a wild guess really. Sorry.
    global $wpdb;
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_type='post' AND post_status='publish' AND post_date > %s";
    $count = $wpdb->get_var( 
        $wpdb->prepare( 
            $query, 
            get_the_date( /* probably needs a better date format here */ ) 
        )
   );
```

Another option I can think of is to append a GET parameter on your links from your front page, since you get the posts there anyway.

```
    <?php $count++ // in the loop right? ?>
    <a href="<?php echo the_permalink();?>?index=<?php echo $count?>"?>

This would of course not work unless everyone uses the frontpage to go to your pages, but then you could count newer posts as a fallback.
```